# Bash alias to run maven jar file that has a version number

Tags: bash

I regularly build the same maven projects and run the built jar file, and would like a bash alias to do this.

Trouble I'm having is ignoring the version number that is in the jar name. For example, the command to run the jar would be:

```
java -jar my-app/target/my-app-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-microservice.jar --VERSION=1.10.0 --server.port=9032
```

I need an alias like `start-my-app` without having hard code the version because it changes regularly. I need to extract the version number somehow and add it back into the alias.

Comment: Use a function, not an alias, if you need any kind of logic at all. Aliases are simple prefix substitution; they can't run code.

Comment: Also, have you made any attempt to do this yourself so you could ask about a specific problem you encountered? Right now this reads as a "please write some code for me" request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want logic, you need a function, not an alias.

Note the change from `start-my-app` to `startMyApp` for stricter POSIX compliance -- the former will work in practice with recent enough versions of bash, but the latter is guaranteed to be supported as a function name in all POSIXy shells. (Arrays are a bashism, but they provide actual utility in a way dashes in names do not).

```sh
startMyApp() {
  local version
  local -a jars

  # generate an array of possible jar names
  jars=( my-app/target/my-app-*-SNAPSHOT-microservice.jar )

  # first element of the array is not a jar that actually exists? Fail.
  [[ -e ${jars[0]} || -L ${jars[0]} ]] || {
    echo "ERROR: No candidate jar found under my-app/target" >&2
    return 1
  }

  # Array has more than one element? Fail.
  (( ${#jars[@]} == 1 )) || {
    echo "ERROR: More than one candidate jar found under my-app/target" >&2
    return 1
  }

  # Extract the version number from the filename
  version=${jars[0]%-SNAPSHOT-*}  # trim -SNAPSHOT-* from the end
  version=${version##*-}          # and early part of the filename
  
  java -jar "${jars[0]}" --VERSION="$version" --server.port=9032 "$@"
}
```